# laravel get array from text in voyager

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

trying to save Text as array in database so i write

```
  some Text
  some Text,
  some Text;
  some Text.
```

and it being saved in databse as

```
        ["some Text\r\nsome Text,\r\nsome Text;\r\nsome Text."]
```

how can i save it in this format

```
        ["some Text" ,"some Text,","some Text;" , "some Text."]
```

is there  any break or something

```
protected $casts = [
'array_value' => 'array',
];


public function setArrayValueAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['array_value'] = json_encode($value);
}

public function getArrayValueAttribute($value)
{
    return collect(json_decode($value));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just brute force it in the setter.

```
public function setArrayValueAttribute($value)
{
    $newArray = [];
    foreach($value as $item) {
        $items = explode("\r\n", $item);
        array_push($newArray, $items);
    }

    $this->attributes['array_value'] = json_encode($newArray);
}
```

But that will only work for your example use case above. If you're expecting any other types of new line characters, you'll have to deal with them also.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the exact same issue and fixed it by using **text** or **varchar** for database column type instead of **JSON**. I know it's bit dirty but worked for me